# How to access a property while binding an array with CGridView in YII

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions, cgridview

I have a grid in which I need to bind a list of months. I have create a list of months and bind it to the list as shown below.

```
$items = $this->getMonths();
         $dataProvider= new CArrayDataProvider(array(),array('keyField'=>false));   
         $dataProvider->setData($items);
$this->render('monthlyReports',
               array('model'=>$this->loadModel($_POST['Users']['user_id']),
              'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,));
```

Upto this every thing is working fine. Now in the view file I have the following code

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'users-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'columns'=>array(
    'Months',
    array(
    'name'=>'Months',
    'value'=>'$data->Months'),
)));
```

Now the problem is that I am not able to access Months as **$data->Months** in the View file where as if I directly access months I can do so. How can I access the Months as **$data->Months**. The $items array that I am passing has the following values:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Months] => January
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Months] => February
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Months] => March
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Months] => April
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Months] => May
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [Months] => June
    )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing array data so you need to access your data as `'$data["Months"]'`.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to do this. Ex:

Controller:

```
$monthList = $this->getMonths();

$this->render('monthlyReports',
               array('model'=>$this->loadModel($_POST['Users']['user_id']),
               'monthList'=>$monthList, // Pass the month list to the view
              'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,));
```

View:

```
array(
    'name'=>'Months',
    'value'=>function ($data, $row) use ($monthList){ return $data->Month? $monthList[$data->Month]['Months'] : '' ; }, // $data->Month it's the model attribute with the month value.
),
```

Comment: If the value of saved month start with '1' to show the correct month of array list, put: $monthList[$data->Month-1]['Months']